# How to enlarge the memory limit of google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, memory

For a certain usage, I need to process large amount of data in Google Chrome. But when the memory usage of the browser tab is larger than 1GB, it get crashed. Is there any way to enlarge the memory limit of Google Chrome?
Thanks.

Chrome Crash Report:

Chrome Version: 30.0.1599.101

Operating System:"Windows 7, 32bits"

URL (if applicable) where crash occurred:

Can you reproduce this crash?Yes

What steps will reproduce this crash? (or if it's not reproducible, what were you doing just before the crash)?

1.set length in the site to 3M

2.Press "Create!"

3.After the server responses, the page crashes when executing the javascript.

Comment: Why are you trying to process 1Gb of data in a browser? Javascript is not the tool for this.

Comment: We try to develop a web-technology-based appilcation for processing biological data.

Comment: are you using a 32bit or a 64bit OS? Which OS do you use? Actually it should crash at about 1.25 GB :-P

Comment: Check in `chrome://crashes/` the crash and post the report here, most likely this is due to your 32bit system

Comment: can you post it here please, we cannot follow this link (403 forbidden)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the issue, the memory goes up to about 1.25GB and my CPU stays running (64bit Win7, 32bit chrome), nothing happens after

Try using a 64bit system with more memory and a 64bit browser, most likely you can allocate more memory by doing this.

As Mike suggested maybe JS is not the right choice for such big data (obviously there are better languages like python for processing such an amount of data).

Comment: this doesn't answer to the question: do you really mean that there is no way to enlarge the memory size in Chrome? Dont know how python could make a difference.